# Converting a C struct to FFI::Struct

Tags: ruby, libpcap, ffi

I am having difficulty setting up a struct from the pcap library in FFI.

Struct:

```
struct pcap_if {
struct pcap_if *next;
char *name;        
char *description;    
struct pcap_addr *addresses;
bpf_u_int32 flags;    
};
```

The relevant Ruby code

```
module Pcap
extend FFI::Library
ffi_lib 'pcap'

attach_function :pcap_findalldevs,[:pointer,:string],:int

class Pcap_if < FFI::Struct
layout :next,:pointer,
   :name,:string,
   :description,:string,
   :pcap_addr,:pointer,
   :flags,:int
end
end
```

Above attached function definition

```
int    pcap_findalldevs(pcap_if_t **, char *)
```

The test code(run as root)

```
tmp=''
ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new :pointer
res = Pcap.pcap_findalldevs ptr,tmp
devs = Pcap::Pcap_if.new ptr
puts res
puts devs.offsets
puts devs[:name]
```

The output is

```
0 #pcap_findalldevs return success
next
0
name
4
description
8
pcap_addr
12
flags
16
pcap.rb:29:in `[]': Memory access offset=4 size=4 is out of bounds (IndexError)
```

The offsets look right to me but my C is very rusty. I was expecting 2 devices: lo and eth0 as names.

Answer (score 1):

Slow post:
Code should go like this:

```
ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new Pcap::Pcap_if.size
res = Pcap.pcap_findalldevs ptr,tmp
devs = Pcap::Pcap_if.new ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. FFI can't deal with pcap_if_t **. I wrote a C function to return just an array of structs.

```
pcap_if_t* find_devs()
{
   pcap_if_t *devs; 
   char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
   int res;
   res=pcap_findalldevs(&devs, errbuf); 
   return devs;
 }
```

I still need to handle error cases, but this does work.